# How to let Jenkins listen to port 80?

Tags: jenkins

With the default configuration, Jenkins is listening to port 8080:

```
$ ss -tulpn | grep 8080
tcp  LISTEN 0      50       *:8080            *:*     users:(("java",pid=3052,fd=115)
```

However, I want to change that and have Jenkins listen to port 80.

When I go into `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` and change `JENKINS_PORT` to `JENKINS_PORT="80"` and restart `sudo service jenkins restart`, I get:

```
$ ss -tulpn | grep 8080
$ ss -tulpn | grep 80
$ curl localhost:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
$ curl localhost:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

How can I let Jenkins listen to port 80?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only root is able to bind to ports below 1024. This is why jenkins by default runs on port `8080`, because they are not part of the priviledged ports. One way to solve this is to have a reverse proxy infront of jenkins, like `apache` or `nginx`, listening on port `80`. Then, it should forward the traffic to the backend, which is jenkins on port 8080. I strongly advise against setting jenkins directly to port 80. Another way to solve this is using iptables. Have a look at this thread and see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14347820) will help you solve your issue.
[This](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application-development/9781784390891/1/ch01lvl1sec11/running-jenkins-behind-an-nginx-reverse-proxy) is one of the many tutorials, how to run jenkins behind nginx or apache

Comment: Wonderful explanation! Thank you so much. Out of curiosity: how would I do that for Jenkins: "Only root is able to bind to ports below 1024"? Is that even possible?

Comment: yes, if the process runs as root. But this will ruin the whole jenkins logic, in terms of security and permissions at a pipeline level for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running systemd, a much cleaner answer is to give the process the capability to bind to the service ports.  Run `systemctl edit jenkins.service` and add the following section:

```
[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_PORT=80"
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
```

Then restart the service.  Similar solution for binding to 443 if you need HTTPS.